# sys.argv ussage in python

Tags: python, argv

I was just wondering how to use in this specific program the `sys.argv` list for command line arguments instead of the input method. As `argc` does not exist in python, the length will be determent with the `len` method, right?

Thanks for any help in advance!

````
MORSE_CODE_DICT = {
    'A':'.-',
    'B':'-...',
    'C':'-.-.',
    'D':'-..',
    'E':'.',
    'F':'..-.',
    'G':'--.',
    'H':'....',
    'I':'..',
    'J':'.---',
    'K':'-.-',
    'L':'.-..',
    'M':'--',
    'N':'-.',
    'O':'---',
    'P':'.--.',
    'Q':'--.-',
    'R':'.-.',
    'S':'...',
    'T':'-',
    'U':'..-',
    'V':'...-',
    'W':'.--',
    'X':'-..-',
    'Y':'-.--',
    'Z':'--..',
    '1':'.----',
    '2':'..---',
    '3':'...--',
    '4':'....-',
    '5':'.....',
    '6':'-....',
    '7':'--...',
    '8':'---..',
    '9':'----.',
    '0':'-----',
}

```python

def encryptor(text):
    encrypted_text = ""
    for letters in text:
        if letters != " ":
            encrypted_text = encrypted_text + MORSE_CODE_DICT.get(letters) + " "
        else:
            encrypted_text += " "
    print(encrypted_text)

text_to_encrypt = input("Enter Some Text To Encrypt : ").upper()
encryptor(text_to_encrypt)
````

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Comment: Regarding "argc" you are right but "len" is a usual function, not a method.

Comment: Correct, `argc = len(sys.argv)`. You probably want to fetch input from `sys.argv[1]`, then make sure you quote the text whenever you call your program. e.g. `python myprogram "my text to encrypt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of `sys.argv` is the name of the executing program. The remaining are the parameters passed to the program, as managed by the shell. For instance, with file name expansion `*.txt` will expand into a separate element for each text file found. You can write a test program to see different expansions

test.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Two ways to run that would be

```
$ python test.py hello there buckaroo
['test.py', 'hello', 'there', 'buckaroo']
$ python test.py "hello there buckaroo"
['test.py', 'hello there buckaroo']
```

An easy solution for you is to just concatenate the arguments so that a person can input with or without quotes

```
import sys
text_to_encrypt = " ".join(sys.argv[1:]).upper()
encryptor(text_to_encrypt)
```

Adding that code we get

```
$ python morsecoder.py hello there buckaroo
.... . .-.. .-.. ---  - .... . .-. .  -... ..- -.-. -.- .- .-. --- ---
```

Notice we don't need to know the length of argv specifically. Python likes to iterate - its often the case that if you need the length of something, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` = list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name.

You can try something like this, and also you can user `strip()` method  to remove leading/trailing and characters (space is the default leading character to remove)

```py
def encrypt():
    return "".join([MORSE_CODE_DICT.get(letter,"NA") for word in sys.argv[1:] for letter in word])
```